# Add multiple tensors inplace in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I can add two tensors `x` and `y` inplace like this

```
x = x.add(y)
```

Is there a way of doing the same with three or more tensors given all tensors have same dimensions?

Comment: you say "in place" but the add method you have in the example is not in place. care to elaborate what it is you desire?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```py
result = torch.sum(torch.stack([x, y, ...]), dim=0)
```

Without stack:

```py
from functools import reduce

result = reduce(torch.add, [x, y, ...])
```

**EDIT**

As @LudvigH pointed out, the second method is not as memory-efficient, as inplace addition. So it's better like this:

```py
from functools import reduce

result = reduce(
    torch.Tensor.add_,
    [x, y, ...],
    torch.zeros_like(x)  # optionally set initial element to avoid changing `x`
)
```

Comment: Is there any noticeable differences between the two? will they trigger the same amount of memory allocations?

Comment: @LudvigH the second option doesn't create a stacked tensor, so it has to be more memory-efficient.

Comment: good point! 

...but does it allocate memory for each intermediate calculation? then it would have to allocate about the same amount of memory in total, but in smaller chunks. this does not feel obvious to me. in not proficient enough with pytorch profiling either to investigate myself.

Comment: `reduce` here is just a fancy way of doing things sequentially like `acc=x; for s in [y, z, ...]: acc=acc+s`. So, it shouldn't store all of the past `acc` values during computation.

Comment: i'm sorry, but it seems it does. ill post another answer elaborating.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Updated mine as well.

Answer (score 3):

In general, in-place operations in PyTorch is tricky. They discourage using it. I think it stems from the fact that it is easy to mess up, ruinig the computation graph and giving you unexpected results. Also, there are many GPU optimizations that will be done anyway, and forcing in place operations can slow down your performance in the end. But assuming that your really know what you are doing, and you want to sum a lot of tensors with compatible shapes I would use the following pattern:

```py
import functools
import operator

list_of_tensors = [a, b, c] # some tensors previously defined
functools.reduce(operator.iadd, list_of_tensors)
### now tensor a in the in-place sum of all the tensors
```

It builds on the pattern of `reduce`, which means "do this to all elements in the list/iterable", and `operator.iadd` which means `+=`. There are many caveats with `+=`, since it may mess up with scoping and behaves unexpectedly with immutable variables such as strings. But in the context of PyTorch, it does what we want. It makes calls to `add_`.

---

Below, you can see a simple benchmark.

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import iadd
import torch


def make_tensors():
    return [torch.randn(5, 5) for _ in range(1000)]


def profile_action(label, action):
    print(label)
    list_of_tensors = make_tensors()
    with torch.autograd.profiler.profile(
        profile_memory=True, record_shapes=True
    ) as prof:
        action(list_of_tensors)

    print(prof.key_averages().table(sort_by="self_cpu_memory_usage"))


profile_action("Case A:", lambda tensors: torch.sum(torch.stack(tensors), dim=0))
profile_action("Case B:", lambda tensors: sum(tensors))
profile_action("Case C:", lambda tensors: reduce(torch.add, tensors))
profile_action("Case C:", lambda tensors: reduce(iadd, tensors))
```

The results vary between runs of course, bit this copy-paste was somewhat representative on my machine. Try it on yours! It probably changes a bit with pytorch version as well...

```
--------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
                Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg       CPU Mem  Self CPU Mem    # of Calls
--------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
       aten::resize_         0.14%      14.200us         0.14%      14.200us      14.200us      97.66 Kb      97.66 Kb             1
         aten::empty         0.06%       5.800us         0.06%       5.800us       2.900us         100 b         100 b             2
         aten::stack        17.38%       1.751ms        98.71%       9.945ms       9.945ms      97.66 Kb           0 b             1
     aten::unsqueeze        30.55%       3.078ms        78.55%       7.914ms       7.914us           0 b           0 b          1000
    aten::as_strided        48.02%       4.837ms        48.02%       4.837ms       4.833us           0 b           0 b          1001
           aten::cat         0.73%      73.800us         2.78%     280.000us     280.000us      97.66 Kb           0 b             1
          aten::_cat         1.87%     188.900us         2.05%     206.200us     206.200us      97.66 Kb           0 b             1
           aten::sum         1.09%     109.400us         1.29%     130.100us     130.100us         100 b           0 b             1
         aten::fill_         0.17%      16.700us         0.17%      16.700us      16.700us           0 b           0 b             1
            [memory]         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     -97.75 Kb     -97.75 Kb             2
--------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
Self CPU time total: 10.075ms

-----------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
                   Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg       CPU Mem  Self CPU Mem    # of Calls
-----------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
              aten::add        99.32%      14.711ms       100.00%      14.812ms      14.812us      97.66 Kb      97.65 Kb          1000
    aten::empty_strided         0.07%      10.400us         0.07%      10.400us      10.400us           4 b           4 b             1
               aten::to         0.37%      54.900us         0.68%     100.400us     100.400us           4 b           0 b             1
            aten::copy_         0.24%      35.100us         0.24%      35.100us      35.100us           0 b           0 b             1
               [memory]         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     -97.66 Kb     -97.66 Kb          1002
-----------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
Self CPU time total: 14.812ms

-------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
         Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg       CPU Mem  Self CPU Mem    # of Calls
-------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
    aten::add       100.00%      10.968ms       100.00%      10.968ms      10.979us      97.56 Kb      97.56 Kb           999
     [memory]         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     -97.56 Kb     -97.56 Kb           999
-------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
Self CPU time total: 10.968ms

--------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
          Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg       CPU Mem  Self CPU Mem    # of Calls
--------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
    aten::add_       100.00%       5.184ms       100.00%       5.184ms       5.190us           0 b           0 b           999
--------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
Self CPU time total: 5.184ms
```

I allocate 1000 tensors holding 25 times 32 bit floats (total 100b per tensor, 100kb=97.66Kb in total). The difference in runtime and memory footprint is quite stunning.

Case A, `torch.sum(torch.stack(list_of_tensors), dim=0)` allocates 100kb for the stack, and 100b for the result, taking 10 ms.

Case B `sum` takes 14ms. Mostly because of python overhead I guess. It allocates 10kb for all intermediary results of each addition.

Case C uses `reduce-add` which gets rid of some overhead, gaining in runtime performance (11ms) but still allocating intermediary results. This time, it does not start with a 0-initialization, which `sum` does, so we only do 999 additions instead of 1000, and allocate one intermediate result less. The difference with Case B is minute, and in most runs they had the same runtime.

Case D is my recommended way for in place addition of an iterable/list of tensors. It takes roughly half the time and allocates no extra memory. Efficient. But you waste the first tensor in the list, since you perform the operation in place.

Comment: Nice benchmark! I guess, the cases A,C allocate excess memory due to garbage collector not work immediately.

Comment: It's also interesting that stacking (case A) is the fastest method with CUDA

Comment: indeed! unfortunately, I dont have a GPU on my laptop, so I could not include that.

Answer (score 2):

How important is it that the operations occur in place?

I believe the only way to do addition in place is with the `add_` function.

For example:

```
a = torch.randn(5)
b = torch.randn(5)
c = torch.randn(5)
d = torch.randn(5)

a.add_(b).add_(c).add_(d) # in place addition of a+b+c+d
```